# Программа не правильно считает символы

Tags: python, pascal

В задании на решу егэ [*Тут*](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=27421) В ответе 35, в моем решении на пайтон выходит 34, помогите найти ошибку в коде

```
f = open("24_demo.txt", "r");
c1=None
c2=None
k = 0
k_max = 0
while 1:
   c1=f.read(1)
   if c1 != c2:
        k+=1
        if k >= k_max:
            k_max = k
    elif c1 == c2:
        k = 0
    c2=c1
    if not c2:
        break
print(k_max)
f.close()
```

Comment: Было бы замечательно, если бы Вы потрудились объяснить что тут в коде происходит, и что содержит текстовый файл !

Comment: Я оставил ссылку на задание с решу егэ, специально чтобы не переписывать сюда условие....

Comment: Кажется, что разница между "сделайте за меня" и "отладьте за меня" - очень тонкая, а, по-моему мнению, её вообще нет и это делает вопрос не соответствующим тематике сайта. Здесь нужно выставить пару принтов и прогнать код на небольших входных данных вручную, шаг за шагом. На чем именно возникло затруднение?

Comment: В программе на паскале по ссылке используется условие {if (c1 <> c2) and (c2 <> '0') then begin} которое содержит проверку c2 <> '0' являющуюся некорректной ! В случае если Файл данных будет содержать символы '0' они будут пропускаться не участвуя в подсчете // этого бага в твоей программе нет //

Comment: В твоем же коде - присвоение k_max выполняется в ветке then, в то время как в проге на паскале это же присвоение в ветке else